# Send Receive multiple files over a socket

Tags: java, sockets

Iv been unable to get this code to work after 2 days of trying everything I can think of. I am aware this exact question has been asked and answered but I am still unable to get mine working correctly. I am trying to send multiple files over a socket.

Iv modified the code to receive the file size before each receive but it still will not work correctly. I can get it to send all of the data into a single file but when I apply the while loops suggested in other posts it either only sends 1 file and then stops or nothing at all. Can someone please correct this if possible so I can move on. Its been almost a week since iv had this issue and even though I understand what I need to do I cant quite manage to get the syntax correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Receive code:**

```
 private void receiveFile() throws IOException{

        String fileToReceive = "test" + increment;
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        DataInputStream inputs = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());


        long fileLength = inputs.readLong();
        int total = 0;

        //receive file
        try{
          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)fileLength];
          is = connection.getInputStream();
          fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToReceive);
          bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
          bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);


          while(fileLength > 0 &&(total = is.read(mybytearray, 0, (int)Math.min(mybytearray.length, fileLength))) != -1){
             bos.write(mybytearray, 0, total);
             fileLength -= total;
          }


          System.out.println("File " + fileToReceive + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
        }finally{
//          if (fos != null) fos.close();
//          if (bos != null) bos.close();
//          if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }   
        increment += 1;
      }
}
```

**Send Code**

```
public void sendFile(String file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream dos = null;
    DataOutputStream outputs = new DataOutputStream(connection2.getOutputStream());

    try{
        dos = connection2.getOutputStream();
        File myFile = new File (file);
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];

        outputs.writeLong(myFile.length());

        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dos.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        System.out.println("Sent " + file + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
        dos.flush();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't copied the code from the duplicated question correctly. You still have an extra `read() `before the reading loop in the receive code. Also your sending code assumes that `read()` fills the buffer. It should also have a loop. It isn't necessary to use a buffer the size of the file at either end.

Comment: I give up. I understand what I need to do I just cant get the sytax correct. Never used sockets for file transfers until last week and while it does work and sends all the files I just cant get it to split them up. This is wasting too much time for something that should be such an easy fix if only someone would just correct my code so I can see where I went wrong...

Comment: Get rid of the first read in the receiving code, before the loop. I've already told you that, and I've already pointed you to working code.

Comment: I understand the receive code and have removed the duplicate read. The while loop for the send code is not in your working code you pointed out. My sending code is the same as anyone elses I can find...

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the code which manages the Socket object itself, but it sounds like you are trying to re-open the socket, which is not possible. From the JavaDoc:

> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.

Your best option is to keep the socket open and just flush it at the end of each file. You will then need a simple way to tell when a file ends (since the socket is nothing more but a string of bytes flowing between the two end points).

The easiest approach is to send the size of the file first in a predefined number of bytes (say 8 bytes to be on the extreme safe side). When sending a file, you send the 8 bytes first and then the content of the file. The receiver knows to expect this sequence, so it reads 8 bytes, parses them to figure out how many bytes represent the file and keeps reading the file until it reaches this number. Then, it start waiting for another 8 bytes.